# ASP.NET MVC2 has 3 tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

There are 3 tags for ASP.NET MVC2
(one with . one with - and one with RTM.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually 6 six tags for ASP.NET MVC 2

- asp.net-mvc-2
- asp-met-mvc2
- asp-net-mvc-2
- asp.met-mvc2
- mvc2
- mvc-2

Thankfully they are all mapped to one tag [asp.net-mvc-2](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-2)

See the synonyms page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-mvc-2/synonyms) for confirmation